# Piping Data from CSV File to OLEDB Destination in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv, ssis

I have a SSIS package in which I use a ForEach Container to loop through a folder destination and pull a single .csv file.

[image: Figure 1]

The Container takes the file it finds and uses the file name for the ConnectionString of a Flat File Connection Manager.

Within the Container, I have a Data Flow Task to move row data from the .csv file (using the Flat File Connection Manager) into an OLEDB destination (this has another OLEDB Connection Manager it uses).

[image: Figure 2]

When I try to execute this container, it can grab the file name, load it into the Flat File Connection Manager, and begin to transfer row data; however, it continually errors out before moving any data - namely over two issues:

*Error: 0xC02020A1 at Move Settlement File Data Into Temp Table, SettlementData_YYYYMM [1143]: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column ""MONTHS_REMAIN"" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".*

*Error: 0xC02020A1 at Move Settlement File Data Into Temp Table, Flat File Source [665]: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column ""CUST_NAME"" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".*

In my research so far, I know that you can set what conditions to force an error-out failure and choose to ignore failures from Truncation in the Connection Manager; however, because the Flat File Connection Manager's ConnectionString is re-made each time the Container executes, it does not seem to hold on to those option settings. It also, in my experience, should be picking the largest value from the dataset when the Connection Manager chooses the OutputColumnWidth for each column, so I don't quite understand how it is truncating names there (the DB is set up as VARCHAR(255) so there's plenty of room there).

As for the failed data conversions, I also do not understand how that can happen when the column referenced is using simple Int values, and both the Connection Manager AND the receiving DB are using floats, which should encompass the Int data (am I unaware that you cannot convert Int into Float?).

It's been my experience that some .csv files don't play well in SSIS when going directly into a DB destination; so, would it be better to transform the .csv into a .xlsx file, which plays much nicer going into a DB, or is there something else I am missing to easily move massive amounts of data from a .csv file into a DB - OR, am I just being stupid and turning a trivial matter into something bigger than it is?

*Note: The reason I am dynamically setting the file in the Flat File Connection Manager is that the .csv file will have a set name appended with the month/year it was produced as part of a repeating process, and so I use the constant part of the name to grab it regardless of the date info*

EDIT:
Here is a screen cap of my Flat File Connection Manager previewing some of the data that it will try to pipe through. I noticed some of these rows have quotes around them, and wanted to make sure that wouldn't affect anything adversely - the column having issues is the MONTHS_REMAIN one[image]

Comment: Even if the underlying connection changes, the Error Output settings you have defined for the Flat File Source component should persist. Rarely do XLSX files make things easier in SSIS.  The XLSX connector often [guesses the datatype of Excel columns wrong](https://www.concentra.co.uk/blog/why-ssis-always-gets-excel-data-types-wrong-and-how-to-fix-it). And Excel files bring with them the complexity of file handles.  If someone else has the Excel file open, while the package is trying to process it, then the package will fail. Stick with CSVs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that one of the csv files in the suite you are processing is malformed?  For instance, if one of the files had an extra column/comma, then that could force a varchar column into an integer column, producing error similar to the ones you have described.   Have you tried using error row redirection to confirm that all of your csv files are formed correctly?

To use error row redirection, update your `Flat File Source` and adjust the `Error Output` settings to redirect rows.  Your Flat File Source component will now have an extra red arrow which you can connect to a destination.  Drag the red arrow from your source component to a new conditional split. Next, right-click the red line and add dataviewer.  Now, when error rows are processed, they will flow over the red line into the data viewer so you can examine them.  Last, Execute the package and wait for the dataviewer to capture the errant rows for examination.

[image]

Do the data values captured by the data viewer look correct? Good luck!

Comment: So doing as you demonstrated here, every row errors out to the data viewer path, with message "The data value cannot be converted for reasons other than sign mismatch or data overflow."

The column that seems to be problematic contains negative and positive whole numbers, and in my Flat File Connection Manager I have the DataType set as DT_I4, with the receiving OLEDB destination set as an Integer. Does this seem incorrect for this type of data?

Comment: If EVERY row errors then we have a fundamental issue.   It sounds like the datatype of the columns for the SettlementData_YYYYMM connection are misdefined.  From your image, the `"MONTHS_REMAIN"` column contains values of `-54.00` and `"194"`.   `"194"` is not a DT_I4 datatype.  These are DT_WSTR columns.  Copy your existing connection manager and redefine all of the columns to DT_WSTR columns and try again.   Once you have the source working without errors, then work on converting these columns from DT_WSTR to DT_I4.   Add a Derived Column Component to replace to double quotes and convert

Comment: Sample Derived Column Transformation code to strip quotes and convert to DT_I4.  `(DT_I4)REPLACE([MyColumn], "\"", "")`.   You will need to do this on all columns.

Comment: So I was able to take all the columns in the file (whackiest data set I've ever seen) and turn them into DT_WSTR, then go into the DB as nvarchar, and it works now. Not a perfect solution, but it's the best that can be achieved with such an irresponsible set of file data

Comment: Good to hear.  One last question.  Ignore the previewer for a moment, if you open the file in notepad.  Is every value surrounded by double quotes?  If so, then good.  What you have is a **text qualified** file.  Set the `Text Qualifier` option in your Flat File Source connection manager.  Choose a double-quote character.  This will strip those quotes for you and you may even be able to pipe them straight into the original table that used integer data types, etc.  See [here](http://www.msbiguide.com/text-qualifier-property-in-ssis/) for more info.

Comment: It is a text qualified file, so I'll see how that handles with the option checked. Thanks again!